# Противительные союзы "ХОТЯ" и "НО"?

Tags: союзы

В чем отличие противительного союза "ХОТЯ" от противительного союза "НО"? Во всех словарях указывается, что противительный союз "ХОТЯ" - это тоже самое, что "НО" и "ОДНАКО". Но между ними нельзя поставить знак равенства. Жду ответа.

Answer (score 2):

А теперь внимание, это именно **ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС** (в первом ответе был дан справочный материал).  Примечание. Речь идет  о союзе ХОТЯ (не о частице). Союз используется **для связи слов и предложений,** в отличие от частицы.

1. **Смысл вопроса понятен:** союзы ХОТЯ, НО, ОДНАКО часто считают равнозначными, синонимичными и заменяющими друг друга. Но так ли это? **Нет, знак равенства между ними ставить нельзя.**
2. Союзы даже **формально** являются разными: ХОТЯ – **подчинительный уступительный** союз, а НО, ОДНАКО –  **сочинительные противительные** союзы.
3. Но союз ХОТЯ имеет **два основных значения**: (1) собственно-уступительное и (2) противительно-уступительное.

В значении (1) ХОТЯ синонимичен уступительному союзу **НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО** и к противительным союзам отношения не имеет: *Им нравилось здесь,  **хотя** (несмотря на то что)  погода испортилась.*

В значении (2) союзы **сближаются по семантике**, но разница в смысловых оттенках остается: на первом месте  или уступительное, или противительное значение.

4. **Противительно-уступительные** отношения выражены противительными союзами НО, ОДНАКО:  *Все окна были настежь, **но** это не помогало.*

**Уступительно-противительные** отношения выражены уступительным союзом ХОТЯ: ***Хотя** все окна были настежь, это не помогало.*

5. Также существует **двойной уступительный** союз ХОТЯ…НО: ***Хотя** еще март, **но** на улице тепло по-весеннему.*

Comment: Противительно-уступительные и Уступительно-противительные. Что то не совсем понимаю. В чем все таки между ними разница?

Answer (score 1):

Это **СПРАВОЧНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ** для ответа (еще не сам ответ)

1. По-моему, в словаре Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру есть ответ на этот вопрос:

ХОТЯ. **I. союз.** 1. Соединяет придаточные **уступительные предложения и обороты;** ***несмотря на то, что***. Не могла уснуть, х. хотела спать. Зажёг свет, х. было светло. Х. закон принят, его игнорируют. 2. Соединяет **противопоставляемые** члены предложения; **однако, но**. Она тоже пела, х. плохо. Много работал, х. денег всё равно не было.

**II. частица. (с частицей бы).** Хоть бы. Спойте х. бы немножко. Съешьте х. бы кусочек. Не люблю, когда опаздывают х. бы на пять минут. Не давала никому своих книг, х. бы на время. Хотя бы и так (хоть бы и так).

2. Посмотрела материал **в учебнике по синтаксису**.

Там НО и ОДНАКО — **противительные сочинительные союзы**, но они обозначают противительно-уступительные отношения (все окна были настежь, но это не помогало).

А вот союз ХОТЯ формально является **уступительным подчинительным** союзом, но кроме собственно-уступительного значения (несмотря на) может иметь **уступительно-сопоставительное значение** (это п.2 из словаря Кузнецова). Он отказался от поездки, хотя раньше о ней мечтал.

Таким образом, мы считаем союз ХОТЯ уступительным подчинительным, а союзы НО, ОДНАКО — сочинительными противительными. Но по семантике между ними возможно **сближение**. Поэтому СУЩЕСТВУЕТ и составной уступительный союз ХОТЯ...НО/ОДНАКО..

Comment: поясните понятие "уступительный"...

Comment: Уступительные союзы используются в СПП с придаточными уступки. Общее грамматическое значение: в придаточной части сообщается о ситуации, которая препятствует или противоречит ситуации главной части. Например: Хотя шел дождь, мы решили прогуляться.  Более ожидаемое следствие - это остаться дома из-за дождя,  но здесь естественная причинно-следственная связь нарушается и  более вероятное УСТУПАЕТ место менее вероятному.

Comment: Не могу понять чем является и что выражает "хотя" в нижеуказанном примере: "Я сегодня пойду   в кино, хотя лучше в кафе".

Comment: Или например "Сегодня я пойду в библиотеку, хотя нет ... не пойду.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ 3 (на комментарии)**

*Противительно-уступительные и уступительно-противительные отношения. Что-то не совсем понимаю. В чем все-таки между ними разница?*

*Не могу понять,  чем является и что выражает «хотя» в нижеуказанном примере: «Я сегодня пойду в кино, хотя лучше в кафе». Или  «Сегодня я пойду в библиотеку, хотя нет ... не пойду».*

Итак, продолжаем разговор…

**Что мы знаем из грамматики**

**Сначала  о союзе ХОТЯ**. Надо сказать, что в грамматике этому уступительному подчинительному союзу разрешается  присутствовать только в сложноподчиненных предложениях СПП (в двух значениях: собственно-уступительном и противительно-уступительном), а также он может дифференцировать сочинительную связь между однородными членами, например: *Нужно навестить его или **хотя бы** позвонить. Яблоки вкусные, **хотя и** не очень крупные.*

В сложносочиненных предложениях (ССП) и бессоюзных сложных предложениях (БСП) союзу ХОТЯ **места не находится**, даже в виде конкретизатора значения (что позволительно для наречий или частиц). А вот уступительные отношения в этих конструкциях имеются, например ССП:  *Его имя Вернер, но он русский. Скоро весна, а между тем мороз все сильнее. Прошла уже неделя, а я еще не познакомился с Лиговскими*. БСП: *Его предостерегали – он только смеялся. Отсеки собаке хвост – не будет овца.*

**А вот противительный союз НО обозначает ситуации**, в которых события противоречат, не соответствуют или мешают друг другу, поэтому противительные отношения часто дополняются другими  значениями (ограничительными, **уступительными**, возместительными).

**А теперь подумаем сами**

ХОТЯ – производный союз,  деепричастная форма глагола ***хотеть*** со значением «иметь желание, намерение, стремление». А ведь это **модальное значение**, которое характерно для оценки событий как «реальное, возможное, желаемое». Поэтому он и используется при выборе ситуаций, оценивает их **вероятность**; поэтому и замешан в связи с частицей БЫ (в форме ***хотя бы***).

Можно сказать, что союз ХОТЯ имеет своеобразную  **модальную метку**, и этим, возможно, отличается от союза НО с его категоричностью и определенностью,  например:

(1) Можно пойти в кино, **хотя** лучше в кафе.  Можно пойти в кино, **но** лучше в кафе.

(2) Сегодня  пойду в библиотеку, **хотя** нет, не пойду.  Надо бы пойти в библиотеку, **но** нет, не пойду.

В этих примерах речь идет о выборе решения: второй вариант противоречит первому, как бы требует **«уступить»** ему место, поэтому здесь присутствуют **оба значения,** противительное и уступительное.

В то же время союз ХОТЯ выражает **предпочтение** (уступительно-противительное значение при выборе), а союз НО ближе **к окончательному решению** (противительно-уступительное значение).

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon. Ответ наиполнейший!

Answer (score 0):

Хотя - союз и частица.

Малый академический словарь.( — М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР. Евгеньева А. П.. 1957—1984):

> 1. уступительный союз. То же, что хоть (в 1 знач.). *И хотя [Иван Яковлевич] каждый день брил чужие подбородки, но его собственный был у
>    него вечно не брит. Гоголь, Нос. Анатоль принес две свечки и поставил
>    их на подоконник, хотя было уже совсем светло.* Л. Толстой, Война и
>    мир.
> 2. противительный союз. **Употребляется для соединения противопоставляемых предложений, означает: однако, но**. ***— Я тоже
>    артист, хотя плохой. Тургенев, Дворянское гнездо. Начинаю понемножку
>    оправляться от безденежья, хотя все-таки денег нет.*** Чехов, Письмо Н.
>    А. Лейкину, 31 окт. 1886.
> 3. частица. прост. То же, что хоть (в 4, 5 и 6 знач.). *— Ну, что же? — продолжает Кошка, — Пропой, дружок, хотя немножко.* И. Крылов, Кошка и
>    Соловей. *Мы не знаем даже, прочел ли Батюшков хотя одно стихотворение
>    Пушкина.* Белинский, Сочинения А. Пушкина.
>
> ◊ хотя бы то же, что хоть
> бы. хотя бы и так то же, что хоть бы и так.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/75946/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F

Так что судить можно только по контексту.